# Highlight in a row when the mouse is over a row in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Which component i must use, to obtain a highlight in a row when the mouse is over a row, using the material-table component?

I dint find any property or which component override to obtain that.

Thanks in advace for your time
Best Regards

Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/s/yv13zjr9w9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only this table to have an hover effect, wrap it in another element or give it a class as in the example above:

https://codesandbox.io/s/4wkpp98z69

```
.myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your codesandbok dont have your solutions, but i understand you explanation and did it. 

Using your logic what could be the solutions to change color if that row are cliked?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to copy in the clipboard the forked link :)

Comment: and change different color of the row if clicked?

Comment: You can use :active selector

Answer (score 3):

you could create a css to highlight row

```
tr:hover{
background:gray;
}
```

Refer to sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/y686o6n9